# Which method can b used to display the running time on the timer even after refresh r by reopening the browser using angular2/typescript

Tags: angular

I have a timer which is running perfectly. When I close and reopen the browser the `timer starts counting from first` (i.e) it restarts, instead of continuing. But when I stop the timer the exact run time is displayed on the table. So please help me, how to make the timer to display the running time when I refresh or reopen the browser.
I am here by sharing my codes: Kindly help

**HTML code**

```
<button md-icon-button class="trackingBtn" [disabled]="!this.isPermission" (click)='resumeTimer(currentTask)' [hidden]='play'> 
<md-icon svgIcon="play"></md-icon> 
</button> 
<button md-icon-button class="trackingBtn" [disabled]="!this.isPermission" *ngIf="play" (click)='pauseTimer(currentTask)'> 
<md-icon svgIcon="pause"></md-icon> 
</button>
```

**Ts code**

```
            this.ApiService
            .runningEntries(Email)
            .subscribe(
              entries  => {
               if(entries.current) {
                 this.Task = entries.current;
                 this.playPauseStopUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
                 var last = entries.current.times[entries.current.times.length - 1];
                 if((last.state == 'start') || (last.state == 'pause')) {
                   this.play = true;
                 } else if(last.state == 'pause') {
                   this.play = false;
                 }
               }
            },
            error => {
              //console.log(error);
            });
```

Thank you..